# Is it possible to return the nth field of a table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use PHP to populate drop-down menus with data from certain columns of separate tables. But, I have many menus to populate, so instead of making a function specific to each, I wanted to pass the column name (which is the field, right?) to the function.

Currently I have this for one menu

```
function print_dropdown($query, $link){
   $queried = mysql_query($query, $link);
   $menu = '<select name="wholesaler" id="wholesaler">';
   while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($queried)) {
       $menu .= '<option value="' . $result['id'] . '">' . $result['wholesaler'] . '</option>';
   }
   $menu .= '</select>';
   return $menu;
}
...
<?php echo print_dropdown("SELECT id, wholesaler FROM wholesaler_flag LIMIT 0, 10", $connect_normas_boudoir);
?>
```

But, I'd like to do this:

```
function get_field($table){
    $col_2 = mysql_query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM "$table" WHERE FIELD = 2');
    return $col_2;
}

function print_dropdown($query, $link){
    $queried = mysql_query($query, $link);
    $menu = '<select name="'$col_2'" id="'$col_2'">';
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($queried)) {
        $menu .= '<option value="' . $result['id'] . '">' . $result['$col_2'] . '</option>';
    }
    $menu .= '</select>';
    return $menu;
}
```

...

```
<?php
    get_field(wholesaler_flag);
    echo print_dropdown("SELECT id, wholesaler FROM wholesaler_flag LIMIT 0, 10", $connect_normas_boudoir);
?>
```

Is it bad form to try and select the second field of each table? In my case there are only two columns in each table concerned. But, I understand that in future a new column could, theoretically, be inserted after id. Is there a better way to do this? Please excuse if I've botched up my single and double quotes. Still learning.

**Note:** I've tried `SHOW COLUMNS FROM wholesaler_flag WHERE FIELD = 2;` in the MySQL console. Of course it didn't work, but I thought there might be a way of accessing that. This is the specific area with which my question is concerned.

Comment: Unless you're building some sort of MySQL administration tool, the best thing to do is explicitly name your columns.  Undoubtedly, you won't always want to expose the entire table.

Comment: The columns are explicitly named, but I want to dynamically retrieve the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function print_dropdown($query, $link,$field0,$field1){
    $queried = mysql_query($query, $link);
    $menu = '<select name="'.$field1.'" id="'.$field1.'">';
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($queried)) {
        $menu .= '<option value="' . $result[0] . '">' . $result[1] . '</option>';
    }
    $menu .= '</select>';
    return $menu;
}
```

---

```
<?php
     echo print_dropdown("SELECT id, wholesaler FROM wholesaler_flag LIMIT 0, 10", $connect_normas_boudoir,"id","wholesaler");
?>
```

Since you are passing the sql statement to the function, why not pass the option id and option value name you want. With the above, you should always supply id as first column, name as second column in the sql statement since option value is fixed to first column and value to second column ie `$result[0]` and `$result[1]` respectively.You could try out the above. Thanks.

Comment: Jesus. Brilliant! I was going about this way too hard. I'm both elated to have an answer and frustrated that I didn't think of this. Thank you!

Comment: Also, thank you for showing me the periods in your code. I knew just `"'$variable'"` didn't look right.

Comment: no problem. If your going to use the same name for the dropdownlist name and id. you could just supply one parameter instead of two as in my answer.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I don't need both `<select name='.$field1.'"` and `id='.$field1.'"` because they do the same thing? My understanding was that some browsers work better with name and others with id. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Also, quick question. Why 0 and 1 in `$menu .= '<option value="' . $result[0] . '">' . $result[1] . '</option>';`. Shouldn't these be the values I passed?

Comment: the field0 i pass is useless here since your dropdownlist name and id is same. so, i think field0 can be omitted. the `$result[0]` and `$result[1]` refers to first column and second column in the `SELECT id, wholesaler FROM wholesaler_flag LIMIT 0, 10` . The variable i pass to the function is just for the dropdownlist id/name `'<select name="'.$field1.'" id="'.$field1.'">';`.

Comment: Oh, I see. My assumption was that field0 was for "id" -- in case not all of my tables' primary keys were named id. On your second point, I didn't know I could just put in the number itself. Now I understand. This is where I thought you'd be using field0, i.e. "id". Again, thanks!!

Comment: I ended up converting everything to PDO in the end. But, I at least learned from asking this. (n_n )

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? To select the nth row from a field, if you were doing a *SELECT* query, would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT n-1,1
```

However, you're doing this on the query *SHOW COLUMNS*, which does not rely on the row number. You can select the 5th row or the 50th row (which is not possible anyway in that query) and it would still return the same result (information on the columns of the table).

You can easily pass field/table names to a function and build a query like that. However, in your given example, given the incorrect PHP/SQL syntax, it is unclear what you're trying to accomplish with your functions.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT FEEDBACK:**
You can write a function that will take the table and the target column number, which will then pass back the column name to you. The following function takes your SQL table (i.e. "wholesaler_flag") and the number of the column you want (i.e. 2 as stated in your example).

```
function getColumnName($sqlTable, $targetColumn = 2) {
    $currentColumn = 1; // indicate our starting position for the column traversal

    $theQuery = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $sqlTable); // get columns from table

    // traverse columns until we reach the desired column number; return column name
    while ($theColumn = mysql_fetch_array($theQuery)) {
        if ($currentColumn == $targetColumn) {
            return $theColumn["Field"];
        }

        $currentColumn++;
    }

    return false; // returns Boolean false if column number is not found
}
```

This can be called through:

```
$columnName = getColumnName("wholesaler_flag", 2);
// $columnName = getColumnName("wholesaler_flag"); also works since 2 is set as the function's default column
```

You could also use it to get column 3, 4, etc. or whatever you want. With a little modification, you can also make it return a range of columns.

Comment: I want the name of the second column, not from a row.
Sorry, I know there must be errors in my PHP, but this is all new to me. I'd like to get the name of the column -- in the case of my first example the table is wholesaler_flag with columns id, wholesaler. Instead of making a `function print_dropdown_wholesaler', etc. I want to have one function in which the column name is a variable -- $col_2 in example 2 -- and I want to get that column name with a SQL statement.

Comment: That's a great way to do it. I'll have to remember if I need to do this again in future. I think I mostly need to start thinking about new ways of doing a thing instead of trying the first thing that comes to mind and beating my head on the table trying to make a bad system work. Anyway, thanks. I'm always learning something from you guys.